# Cross posting and morphing from answer to question?

Tags: discussion

I just saw this [How do I find out what areas to avoid to minimize an attack like the murders of the hikers Jespersen and Ueland in Morocco?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/145537/6188) in the travel site which starts off with:

> I am a citizen of Sweden. I am a female. I enjoy spectacular, remote
>   places to travel alone or with one other female friend, including
>   hiking and camping.

Yet the profile moniker is "Ken Thompson" .. decidedly non-female.  OK I can handle that, but when I looked at their profile, I see that they just answered this question on the great outdoors site:

[How can I protect myself in case of a human attack like the murders of the hikers Jespersen and Ueland in Morocco?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/a/23082)

For some reason this cross-posting and turning an answer into a question makes me un-easy.  I'm not sure if my uneasiness is just me, or if it is something that should be addressed.  I don't mind people posting and answering their own questions, but I prefer to see things rooted in reality and actual experience/plans

Comment: The question has been edited as it was mentioned as being cross posted. It was worse than it is now.